# How do I prevent dividing by zero in a for loop evaluation?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, logic, division

in this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 / timeScale; i++)
 {
       ......
 }
```

there is a possibility that during the execution of this loop the variable timescale will become zero.
How do I prevent the error that will come when the loop evaluates 1/timeScale and it comes up as 1/0?

Comment: What are you hoping to do when it is 0? You can just check that condition first if you want to stop.

Comment: keep the loop running infinitely until it is not zero again

Comment: i think `for` is the wrong loop for whatever you're doing. `for` is used in situations where you know _before_ entering the loop how often it's executed. since you say `timeScale` can _become_ 0, you do *not* know how often you have to loop. maybe try a while instead. for example a `while(timeScale != 0)`

Comment: i need to compare it to i though, while( i < 1/timeScale) ?

Comment: If you want to keep it running when `timeScale` is `0` change the check to `timeScale == 0 || i < 1 / timeScale` if you want to stop the iteration then make it `timeScale != 0 && i < 1 / timeScale` that said it's hard to give good advise without being able to see what is actually happing inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> keep the loop running infinitely until it is not zero again

In that case, something like this should do the job:

```
for (int i = 0; timeScale < 0.00001 || i < 1 / timeScale; i++)
{
    // ......
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you're not checking `timeScale == 0` instead? Why 0.00001 specifically?

Comment: Here you go: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith

Comment: semi-valid point - shouldn't a division-by-zero-error only occure when dividing by _exactly_ zero, and not when dividing by _almost_ zero?

Comment: if you're that close to 0, the division would be close to infinity and pass anyway -- splitting hairs.

Comment: should I add ```if (i < 0) { i = 0; }``` inside the loop incase the i rolls over to negative during the loop?